# Match bicycle routes to street lines

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, kml, select-by-location, reverse-geocoding

I have a KML layer of bicycle routes and a street line layer.  Using either ArcGIS or QGIS, how can I select the streets that correspond to the bicycle routes?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  In a minute I will add tags for the products you have indicated are available to you but I recommend that you include these (as well as their versions) yourself in future.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap you could use Select By Location queries to select streets that are within a specified distance, intersect, etc a bicycle route. It might also be beneficial to Buffer the streets with their widths to create street polygons that represent the street surface to improve the accuracy of your queries.

Either way, you'll likely need to do some QA/QC by eye after your selections to make sure you're not missing any streets on a route or inadvertently selecting ones that don't belong.

Comment: He'll need to use the [**KML to Layer (Conversion)**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000004w000000) tool to get his KML as a layer first.

Comment: I did already use KML to Layer which gave me the lines that I am trying to match with the streets.  @mplanka The problem with the Select is that I get all the intersecting streets too, so I see this will probably need a lot of manual processing.  I will continue experimenting with the Select options.  Also, I note the helpful tags added to my first post.

Comment: This seems to work pretty well: I buffered the bicycle routes polyline layer that I extracted from the KML; I chose a 50 foot buffer to start.  Then I selected the streets that were completely within the buffer, which effectively eliminates intersecting streets that extend more than 50 feet beyond the route centerline.  The chosen buffer width was reasonable and somewhat arbitrary, certainly open to experimentation.